# Django: search (filter) by FileField.name

Tags: django

I need to find model instances whose FileFields point to a particular set of files. This is probably obvious and documented somewhere but I can't seem to find it: what's the syntax for using FieldField.name in a django filter query? Something like:

```
models.MyModel.objects.filter(image__name='myfile.jpg')
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Nevermind - it's just

```
models.MyModel.objects.filter(image='myfile.jpg')
```

a separate issue was causing me to think this wasn't working, but in fact it is.

Comment: Don't forget to add the 'upload_to' to the image name.

If you have `upload_to` defined in your field (e.g. `upload_to='upload/folder/'`), you should use `models.MyModel.objects.filter(image='upload/folder/myfile.jpg')`

(Came here through Google, 8 years after the question was posted.)

Comment: If you don't want to include the path, just do `models.MyModel.objects.filter(image__endswith='myfile.jpg')`

Comment: Just consider cases when one name is substring of the other like `ab.jpg` and `b.jpg` when using `image__endswith` which may cause problems.